# open any format video file as text

Tags: video, format

I want to see the differences between different video file formats. For that purpose i want to open video files as human readable text files. What is the best way to open any format video file. It would be additional if anyone can tell major differences between video file formats and why some video players supports specific formats for which they are developed for.

Answer (score 4):

For video you generally want to use a Hex editor if you are getting into any detail as the files are often not really set up to be readable in a standard text editor.

You can also get specific tools geared towards a particular format, for example if you are looking at mp4 then mp4 explorer is a useful tool and will present the information in a human readable way: https://mp4explorer.codeplex.com

Comment: It is a tool that (usually...) shows the raw hex and where possible a text representation also. The screen shots here, for example, give a good feel: http://www.hexedit.com/hex-edit-shots.htm or another example here: http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor/screenshots. Comprehensive comparison here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors